# Magento 1.6: Using MySQL datetime fields with resource models

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've set up a database table with a DATETIME field named "release_date", and the model/resource model seem to work fine. However, I want to retrieve and set "release_date" as a Zend_Date object. And I also want to make sure its always stored and retrieved as UTC.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this, or perhaps a better solution all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it in your resource model, something like:

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    ...
    $date = $object->getReleaseDate();
    // convert from your server/client timezone to UTC if needed
    $object->setReleaseDate($this->formatDate($date));
    ...
}

protected function _afterLoad(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    ...
    $date = new Zend_Date($object->getReleaseDate());
    // convert to your server/client timezone from UTC if needed
    $object->setReleaseDate($date);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has surely got me in the right direction. However, when retrieving the models through its collection, _afterLoad() does not seem to be called on the resource model.

Comment: Hmm, you can do the same in appropriate methods of resource collection model.

Comment: I did find the _afterLoadData() method for collections where I could loop through all models and load them individually. This seemed really inefficient. So I ended up with implementing the getReleaseDate() method on the model instead of _afterLoad() on the resource model.