# Magento ouputting incorrect date and time

Tags: magento, date, time, timezone

If I output the date/time in index.php `echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());`. It's correct. If I output the date/time anywhere after that, in an extension for example it's off 4 hours exactly. I've set the timezone properly in php.ini and in Magento itself so not sure what's causing it to be off. I'm running version 1.7.0.2.

**EDIT**

Ok so I've learned a few things.

Magento always sets the timezone to UTC in 
app/mage.php

```
line 767: date_default_timezone_set('UTC')
```

So, basically you can't use date(),time() etc. You have to set your targetting timezone in Admin->System->Configuration / General->Locale options and use something like:

```
$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
echo date('m/d/y h:i:s', $now);
```

I could always replace line 767 with my timezone but I don't like modifying core code. Are there any other options out there ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preferred method in Magento seems to be using either Zend or Varien date-time objects instead of scalar values as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233768/magento-1-6-using-mysql-datetime-fields-with-resource-models).  Once you have your object you can easily convert it to other, non-server timezones with a [`setTimezone`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.overview.html#zend.date.values) call.

```
// a more complete example
$datetime = Zend_Date::now();
// admin controls this output through configuration
$datetime->setLocale(Mage::getStoreConfig(
             Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE))
         ->setTimezone(Mage::getStoreConfig(
             Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE));
echo $datetime->get(Zend_Date::DATETIME_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're saving dates in Magento's database make sure they are in UTC. By default Magento saves all dates as UTC but it's supposed to display them in the local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the time varies in e.g. the system.log but also in Scheduler (cronjobs).

So let's say it is now 01.15 real time, the Created time in Scheduler is always correct, so 01.15 in this case. Than the Executed time is sometimes 01.16 but often 02.16, so you see a mix of 01.16 and 02.16, so the time varies continuous.

When I check the system log, I see the same, first you see times incrementing for messages like 01.50, 02.45, 03.50 and suddenly 02.55 again.

So there is something in the system that let varies this time, but where, maybe my provider find something ... but it is not the system time, it has to do with Magento .. Magento writes to the log ..

EDIT:

Why this problem is there I don't know, but I changed the UTC time in Mage.php in my zone Europe/Amsterdam. Now all times are correct, also in the logs.

But one problem again, when I schedule a cronjob immediately in Scheduler (extension) this job is scheduled 1 hour later (other times in Scheduler are correct). An extension Copernica runs at e.g. 18.00 (not via Scheduler) and writes it is executed last time at 17.00 ... no other non Magento webshops have this kind of problems .. the database is also using Europe/Amsterdam in php.ini ..